# Mongo DB: Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to figure out how exactly I should do when it comes to Spotify API and OAuth2.

The refresh token needs to be stored in a database as the bot cycles and lose the token otherwise. So first time when I start the bot the token it generates a URL that contains an *authentication code*, this code needs to be inserted to the code, and then when I deploy it again it will get me the refresh token and everything I need.

I'm using Mongoose and have managed to get the token stored to Mongo DB.
Though I'm too much of a beginner to figure out how to fetch the token from the databas, and I also don't want to run the authentication again, except a function that refreshed the token.

I have a separate file containing this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  token: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("RefreshToken", tokenSchema);
```

The code below might be a bit heavy. And probably contains a lot of faults. But this is what I'm currently working with (and struggles with).

```
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
var text = '';
var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

var scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email', 'playlist-read-private', 'playlist-modify-private', 'playlist-modify-public'],
  redirectUri = '<my uri>',
  clientId = '<my client id>',
  clientSecret = '<my client secret>',
  state = generateRandomString(16);

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  redirectUri: redirectUri,
  clientId: clientId,
  clientSecret: clientSecret
});

// Create the authorization URL
var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);

var credentials = {
  clientId: '<my client id>',
  clientSecret: '<my client secret>',
  redirectUri: '<my uri>'
};

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi(credentials);

var app = express();

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.redirect(authorizeURL);
});

// The code that's returned as a query parameter to the redirect URI
var code = '<authentication code>';

// Retrieve an access token and a refresh token
client.on('ready', async () => {
  await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_SPECTRUM, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    // useFindAndModify: false,
    keepAlive: true
  }).then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to the Spectrum Database');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  
spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(
  function(data) {
    console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    console.log('The refresh token is ' + data.body['refresh_token']);

    // Set the access token on the API object to use it in later calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);

    // SAVE REFRESH TOKEN TO DB
    const refreshToken = new RefreshToken({
      _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
      token: data.body['refresh_token']
    });
    refreshToken.save()
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refreshToken.token);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Something went wrong!', err);
  }
);
// --------------------------------------------------
// clientId, clientSecret and refreshToken has been set on the api object previous to this call.
function refreshSpotifyToken() {
spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken().then(
  function(data) {
    console.log('The access token has been refreshed!');

    // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
    spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']);
    console.log('The access token is ' + data.body['access_token']);
    console.log('The token expires in ' + data.body['expires_in']);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Could not refresh access token', err);
  });
};

  refreshSpotifyToken();
  setInterval(refreshSpotifyToken, 1000 * 60 * 59);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to get the token from the database? is these token for every person? if so you might add `memberID` from your schema then fetch the token in your command as of following:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const tokenSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, //Sometimes, you dont need to add this it will automatically generate on the mongodb.
  memberID: String
  token: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("RefreshToken", tokenSchema);
```

Then fetch it to your command.

```
const token = require('path_of_file')

const token_user = await token.findOne({
   memberID: message.author.id
})
```

then get your token.

```
console.log(token_user.token) //These how you get the token using memberID
```

EDIT:

You might can use `_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`

```
const token = require('path_of_file')

const token_user = await token.findOne({
   _id: "Your _id from the database" //Copy paste it here
})

console.log(token_user.token)
```

Comment: No, it's just one token. It uses my account to simply add songs that are shared on Discord to a playlist. So when it authenticates and retrieves a token once the bot i up. That token I then need to store in a database and look if it exists when the bot restarts, and if it does, fetch it. But I don't really understand Mongoose and MongoDB. Thanks for this reply though!

Comment: There's no other way tho, You need one ID to fetch the token from the database, since you're updating the token every restart of the bot

Comment: Check my edited answer and try it